# Which is Faster, Getting Count() for each category or querying from Dataset and How to do it

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am currently trying to get number of articles present in each category(specific ID) to show it beside the category name. This is how it looks like [image: categories]

Now I am trying to assign the label control with count to respective categories. I have two options, by running below select query 6 times for each category and assign it.

```
Select Count(Cat) from tbl_blg where Cat ='1' //should do so for all the 6 ID's
```

Or

```
SqlCommand cmdcount = new SqlCommand("SELECT Cat from tbl_blg",cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter dacount = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdcount);
        dacount.Fill(dscount);

        int scount = Convert.ToInt32(dscount.Tables["tbl_blg"].AsEnumerable().Count(r => r.Field<int>("Cat") == 1));
```

---

Now First one will be tedious(6 queries at one go), I believe, correct me if am wrong.

Second one will be better(only one query and assigning it to Dataset) 
however the problem is it is returning null and throwing null exception...

Which one you think is faster ? if it is second option then is my code correct ? it's returning null but should be returning 2

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your second query to.

```
SELECT COUNT(Cat) as Count, Cat FROM tbl_blg
Group by Cat
```

Gives you the count of how much each category is present.
What you are doing now is selecting everything from that table and then do the counting. By doing the group by on query level you limit how much results are being retrieved.

The current query retrieves;

```
Cat1 
Cat1 
Cat1 
Cat1 
Cat2
```

And with group by statement you retrieve;

```
4, Cat1
1, Cat2
```

Doing multiple query is basically a no-go for this situation. Also EF always adds a bit of overhead on your request, so when it is performance critical you could consider using some more low-level ORM like Dapper or start using SQL/Stored procedures.

Comment: is it possible to assign this count value in Repeater control ? second, how to access the count here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a window function.

```
SELECT COUNT() OVER(PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY cat) AS 'Count'
FROM tbl_blg
```

Also if you are going to be calling this code constantly I would highly suggest making it a stored procedure. The benefit of a stored procedure is your sql server doesn't have to recompile the code every time.

Comment: Thank you, but the below answer is working perfectly fine, however now it is returning count and categoryID but the name of these ID's present in another table...how do it get the name of ID, possible in the same same statement ?

Comment: So what you are trying to do is get the categoryid and the count for each? If so please edit your post to include the table definitions and i will be able to help you.

Comment: Am really sorry for the incomplete question. First table(tbl_id) has two columns: CategoryID and CategoryName ..Second table(tbl_blg) is already mentioned previously..now I am able fetch the categoryid which is also present in tbl_blog but how to next go ahead and realize the name which is present first table tbl_id ?

Comment: you need to join both tables and then, instead of selecting and grouping by Tbl_id, you do by CategoryName